# How to get elementRef without constructor injection? - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

I want to know if there is a way to get the `ElementRef` instance without the constructor injection in `Angular`?

**Why I need it:**

I have an abstract BaseComponent class that gets inherited in a lot of other Angular Component classes. I want to avoid injecting the `ElementRef` in all subclasses via `super(elementRef)` call and instead have it directly injected in the BaseComponent class -

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {
   private elementRef: ElementRef;
   constructor() {   
      // Do we have some option like below?
     //  this.elementRef = Injector.get(ElementRef) 
   }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp-one',
  templateUrl: './comp-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp-one.component.css']
})
export class CompOne extends BaseComponent {
    constructor() {  // constructor(elementRef: ElementRef)
      super();            // super(elementRef);  
     // here I can pass elementRef in super constructor call
     // but that's what I don't want to do
   }
}
```

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: @yurzui angular 7

Answer (score 0):

Angular has the `inject(...)` function that can inject tokens during an injection context (such as during the construction of a component, like in your example). The full specs can be found here: https://angular.io/api/core/inject

For `ElementRef`, you can inject it like this:

```
private readonly elementRef: ElementRef = inject(ElementRef);
```

If you want to specify the generic type on `ElementRef`, you can inject it like this:

```
private readonly elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement> = inject<ElementRef<HTMLElement>>(ElementRef);
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test it but i found your question interesting, so i made a few research and i found [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-simplify-components-with-typescript-inheritance/) which resolve the exact problem you want to solve.

Comment: I don't think that solution will work in case of `ElementRef`. `ElementRef` is tied to specific Component/Directive. You can't use module level injector to get that instance. You should be taking it from ElementInjector.